# why the lexer token stopped to go to next level

Tags: antlr4

I got an antlr 4 grammar. Why the lexer token ("NAME") stopped to go to next level ("INPUT_NAME"). thanks

[image]

Comment: Please add all information as text not as image

Comment: What do you mean by "go to the next level"? I think you may be asking why all the letters are recognized as `NAME`s, rather than `INPUT_NAME`s (because `NAME` comes first in the grammar and matches the same content), but your parser grammar uses `NAME`, not `INPUT_NAME`, so you *want* them to be recognized as `NAME`s, don't you?

Comment: Antlr lexers follow two rules: (1) Always match the rule with the longest string. (2) If two or more rules match the same input, the lexer returns the token type of the first rule. You have three rules that match 'a': `NAME`, `INPUT_NAME`, `OUTPUT_NAME`. `NAME` is always chosen because it is listed first. Recommend that your lexer rules never ever overlap in what they can match.

Comment: hi @sepp2k , if i change the parser grammer to INPUT_NAME, it even has error

Comment: @Peter Yes, because they're recognized as `NAME`s, not `INPUT_NAME`s. I'm asking why that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that maybe by "stopped to go to next level" you mean, "Why don't I have an `INPUT_NAME` or `OUTPUT_NAME` node nested under my `NAME` node (like you would expect to see with a parser rule).

That's because Lexer rules generate Tokens which are leaf nodes on the parse tree, there's no such thing as a Token nested under another Token in the tree.

The grammar you have treats `INPUT_NAME` and `OUTPUT_NAME` as though they were fragments used to produce the `NAME` lever rule.

You could get the behavior you're looking for by changing the `NAME` Lexer rule to a `name` parser rule and moving it to the parser grammar.  (That's assuming I've correctly inferred what you're expecting)